# Higher order OR in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here is an example problem I'm thinking about:
Take the sum of every x from 1 to n where x is evenly divisible by 3 or 5, so
something like this:

```
divisible a b = rem b a == 0
sum3or5 n = sum [x | x <- [1..n], divisible 3 x || divisible 5 x]
```

Coming from Scheme, I would like to implement this using a filter, something like this:

```
divisible a b = rem b a == 0
sum3or5 n = sum $ filter div3or5 [1..n] where
    div3or5 n = (divides 3 n) || (divides 5 n)
```

I'm thinking, is there a higher-order logical OR (||), so that I could write 'div3or5' point-free style, something like this?:

```
divisible a b = rem a b == 0
sum3or5 = sum $ filter (divisible 3 || divisible 5) . range
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can "lift" `(||)` from booleans to functions from something to booleans. So you want something like

```
(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

to turn into

```
(||) :: (r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool)
```

This happens to be exactly what the applicative instance of functions are good for.

```
liftA2      :: (a -> b -> c) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b) -> (r -> c)
```

so

```
liftA2 (||) :: (r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool) -> (r -> Bool)
```

which means, in your case, you can write your filter as

```
filter (liftA2 (||) (divides 3) (divides 5))
```

which takes an integral number and decides if it's divisible by 3 or 5.

---

If you want, you can define something like

```
(<||>) = liftA2 (||)
```

or, equivalently,

```
f <||> g = \x -> f x || g x
```

and then you can write your filter as

```
filter (divisible 3 <||> divisible 5)
```

Wrapping angle brackets around operators is sort of an idiom for showing that they are lifted into something else (functor, applicative, monoid).

Comment: `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` is required for `(<||>) = liftA2 (||)`

Comment: @GabrielRiba Or an explicit type signature, which is probably a good idea anyway!

Comment: you are right! I didn't got right in ghci but in a file things are clearer: `(<||>) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool`

Comment: @GabrielRiba Semicolons are convenient for playing in GHCi: `(<||>) :: Applicative f => f Bool -> f Bool -> f Bool; (<||>) = liftA2 (||)`

Comment: @duplode Or just enable multi-line mode from the start. `:set +m` will make GHCi behave more like the Python interpreter in terms of multi-line definitions.

Answer (score 3):

The `Control.Arrow` module will help.

```
import Control.Arrow

divisible a b = rem a b == 0
range a = [1..a]
sum3or5 = sum . filter (divisible 3 .||. divisible 5) . range
a .||. b = (uncurry (||)) . (a &&& b)
```

The `(&&&)` is the fan-in operator, with type `Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')`, and in this case we are using `(->)` as an arrow. This gets us a function `b -> (Bool,Bool)`, and we can then compose this with an uncurried `(||)`, or any other boolean operator.